# Codeigniter - Custom 404 Pages (unable to Extend CI_Exceptions)

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Trying to extend codeigniters CI_Exceptions class so i can override the show_404 method but I just get fatal with the following message:

" Fatal error: Class 'CI_Exceptions' not found "

The contents of MY_Exceptions is as follows:

```
class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions {

    function MY_Exceptions()
    {
        die("reached MY_Exceptions!!");
        //parent::CI_Exceptions();
    }
}
```

The file is located in app/libraries.

I am using codeigniter version 2.0.2

I am using the exact same method to override the core Controller which is working perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Exceptions` class has been moved to core classes. If you want to modify it you need to put it in `application/core/`. Please check [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you!! worked perfectly.  What version did this occur?  For future reference, how would I have been able to tell this by the code?

Comment: Cant remember in which version this has been changed. To get the version-wise changes, you can check [changelogs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/changelog.html). Also you can have an eye in codeigniter community to get updates.